# openssl: how to find the config options that openssl was compiled with

Tags: openssl

Is there an easier way to figure out the options specified during building openssl such as whether OPENSSL_NO_SRTP was defined at that time?
I can only **gleam limited information** from the:

```
openssl version -a
```

command. However if I have just the binaries, is there a way to figure out options such as these? The reason behind this question is that there is a vulnerability "CVE-2014-3513" that is introduced if openssl is not compiled with this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OpenSLL was compiled *with* **OPENSSL_NO_SRTP** then *ssleay32.dll* does not contain functions related with SRTP supprt: `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_use_srtp`, `SSL_get_selected_srtp_profile`, `SSL_set_tlsext_use_srtp`, `SSL_get_srtp_profiles`. Fortunately they all have "srtp" in their names, so you can check if the DLL contains these functions using **dumpbin**. For example:

`dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS ssleay32.dll | findstr /R /C:"srtp"`

In my case it finds these functions, so my OpenSSL was compiled **without** *OPENSSL_NO_SRTP*:

`dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS ssleay32.dll | findstr /R /C:"srtp"
        358   57 00026CD0 SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_use_srtp
        357   AA 00026D00 SSL_get_selected_srtp_profile
        360   B4 00026D10 SSL_get_srtp_profiles
        354   E8 00026D40 SSL_set_tlsext_use_srtp`

I hope that helps to solve your problem.

P.S.
Unfortunately, as far as I know OpenSSL does not record compile time options.

Comment: Thanks. The "without" in bold is really required. :-)

Comment: No problem, I think that "nm" would be even easier to use: "nm -C <whatever>.so | grep srtp"

Comment: Using `dumpbin` and `findstr` is inexact at best. Not a terrible way to make a guess, but there is a much better (supported, reliable) option, which is the `version` command.

Answer (score 13):

You can get most (all?) of the configuration information about the installed `openssl` via the [`version` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/version.html). In particular,

```
openssl version -f
```

will list all the complier flags that were specified at build time.

Comment: flags such as OPENSSL_NO_SRTP do not show up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sirgeorge for the answer. I forgot to specify Linux as the platform so the equivalent check in Linux is:

```
 $ objdump -f libssl.so -x | grep -i SRTP
    0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              d1_srtp.c
    00000000002609e0 l     O .data  0000000000000030              srtp_known_profiles
    000000000003d100 g     F .text  0000000000000012              SSL_set_tlsext_use_srtp
    000000000003cb40 g     F .text  0000000000000149              ssl_parse_serverhello_use_srtp_ext
    000000000003d120 g     F .text  0000000000000012              SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_use_srtp
    000000000003ca90 g     F .text  00000000000000ab              ssl_add_serverhello_use_srtp_ext
    000000000003ca50 g     F .text  0000000000000029              SSL_get_srtp_profiles
    000000000003ca80 g     F .text  0000000000000008              SSL_get_selected_srtp_profile
    000000000003cc90 g     F .text  0000000000000128              ssl_add_clienthello_use_srtp_ext
    000000000003cdc0 g     F .text  0000000000000210              ssl_parse_clienthello_use_srtp_ext
```